# Why is the complex plane shaped like it is?

Tags: complex-numbers

It's always taken for granted that the real number line is perpendicular to multiples of $i$, but why is that? Why isn't $i$ just at some non-90 degree angle to the real number line? Could someone please explain the logic or rationale behind this? It seems self-apparent to me, but I cannot actually see *why* it is.

Furthermore, why is the real number line even straight? Why does it not bend or curve? I suppose arbitrarily it might be strange to bend it, but why couldn't it bend at 0? Is there a proof showing why?

Of course, these things seem natural to me and make sense, but why does the complex plane have its shape? Is there a detailed proof showing precisely why, or is it just an arbitrary choice some person made many years ago that we choose to accept because it makes sense to us?

Comment: Because $i^2=-1$?

Comment: @Bye_World but that doesnt tell us anything about i's location directly... Why couldnt it be above -1 rather than above 0?

Comment: The way we happen to plot real and complex numbers is due to convenience.  If you want to plot real numbers on a wiggly line go ahead.  For instance, there's a 1-1 correspondence between the points on a sine curve and the real numbers.  So it shouldn't make any difference if you, for some reason, decided to plot the real numbers there.

Comment: If you interpret multiplication by a complex number *geometrically*, multiplication of a complex number $v$ by $i$ is equivalent to rotating $v$ by $90^\circ$ counter-clockwise.  Before even knowing that it should be $90^\circ$, we know that the rotation should be the same going from $1$ to $1\cdot i$ as it should be from $i$ to $i\cdot i$.  Since $i^2=-1$, it makes sense that it should be $90^\circ$ rotation.

Comment: You can bend and twist the complex plane (or already the real line) as much as you like. However, in that case the arithmetic operations of addition and multiplication do not correspond to simple geometric transformations any more. If you can live without that, fine. After all, the real line/the complex plane is only a model for and not identical to the field of real/complex numbers

Comment: @Bye_World oh so the complex plane is nothing more than an arbitrary diagram?

Comment: I wouldn't say "arbitrary".  I'd prefer "convenient".

Comment: @Bye_World i mean that whatever diagram we use has no relation to the actual math of the operations. It's like polar coordinates vs cartesian. Literally all that changes is the picture?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I almost fear asking this... Then what *is* the field of complex and real numbers?

Comment: Einstein showed that the gravity fields deform space. So lines may not be straight.

Comment: It actually works the other way around. We discovered we could describe geometry using numbers (not the other way around) and it was so very useful we should as models they are equivalent. A complex number or euclidean 2 space is simply a set of ordered pairs. As Cartesian pair it'd just so darn convenient to put the separate but associated pairs as rectangle coordinates. We could put them at oblique angles but then the "distance" between points wouldn't be consistent with the arbitrary geometry we created....

Comment: .... i.e.  (-1,0) to (0,x) should always be the same size as (1,0) to (0,x).  If we are to have geometry, then that should be a perpendicular bisector.  Similarly just about every comparison makes plane geometry a consistent model.

Comment: While analysis likes usually the real line to be straight with two ends (to place $+\infty$ and $-\infty$), algebra prefers the real line to be in the shape of a circle (with a single point $\infty$ tying both ends together)!

Comment: "It's like polar coordinates vs cartesian. Literally all that changes is the picture?" Usually when someone asks to convert something from polar to Cartesian (or vice versa), they want the picture to _stay the same,_ and all that changes is the _numbers._

Comment: @DavidK sorry. I meant polar graphing vs cartesian graphing.

Comment: John Stillwell, in _Mathematics and Its History,_ 1st ed., pp. 191-192, credits the first attempt at a geometric representation of complex numbers to Wallis, and points out that it (1) was very different from the usual modern graphing of complex numbers and (2) didn't work well. The conventional mapping of the complex numbers onto a Euclidean plane is just so incredibly helpful (with geometric analogies to complex operations) that it's easy to forget that it is not part of the definition of complex numbers at all.

Comment: Take a look at the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1365641/10549. This complements the pithy and relevant first line of [ajotatxe's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1842977/10549). For further insights on the additivity of the $\arg$s of multiplied complex numbers idea, have a look at [this famous lecture](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_22.html) by physicist Richard Feynman.

Comment: nobody talked about $\mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R}(i)  \simeq \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2-1)$ and the fact that it is isomorphic as a field to $\mathbb{R}[x]/(ax^2+bx+c)$ whatever $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, $\ b^2-4ac < 0$  ? finally choosing $a=1,b=0,c=-1$ is the more natural since it reduces the number of terms in the multiplication

Comment: I don’t know why nobody has mentioned this, but it *must* be 90° because the real and imaginary parts are independent. If the imaginary axis was not perpendicular, it would imply that $i$ had some real component, which is clearly not the case — let's imagine for a moment $i=a+bj$ where $j$ corresponds to a perpendicular axis… then $i^2=(a+bj)^2=a^2+b^2j^2+2abj$, which, if $a≠0$, clearly has components corresponding to both the real axis and the $j$ axis and therefore cannot meet the definition $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Shaking my head.

Comment: @copper.hat why? Is this question that stupid?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: No, its not stupid, and it is good to ask questions. There is no reason, a priori, to have the real line be straight, or to draw $i$ as (visually) perpendicular to $1$. But it makes a lot of stuff much harder to visualise/explain. The comment by user1952006 is apropos. At some stage we/someone else just draws it in some simple canonical way and it sticks. Besides, I have just finished a bottle of wine. Now if you could explain what T&& means in c++...

Comment: @copper.hat T&& in c++? How is that relevant. Also, why were you shaking your head?

Comment: @copper.hat : you are right, me neither I don't get none of their explanation of rvalue references. I think nobody really understood what it means (nobody explained in simple words what does the compiler and what is the produced code when using `T&&`)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: My bottle of wine was empty...

Comment: @user1952009 correct me if i am wrong, but copper hat just managed to derail this thread in the most hilarious manner possible, lol.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: It is appropriate that the derailment occurred while commuting home by train...

Comment: @copper.hat That is quite hilarious. Definitely keep up the good work lightening moods! Your comment certainly made my day in terms of humor!

Comment: @user1952009: Scott Meyers is usually my clarifying light on such things, but it is clear that I will have to reread "modern effective c++" many times before I see the light...

Comment: To know what the complex numbers really are, you have to learn a bit of abstract algebra. At least look up Wikipedia for what a field is. Now we can ask the natural question of whether we can construct a field that contains the field of real numbers and also has an element $r$ such that $r^2=-1$. It is not a priori necessarily possible. But it turns out that we can. If such a field exists, $(a+br)(a-br) = a^2+b^2$ for any real $a,b$, so $a+br$ has multiplicative inverse $\frac{a-br}{a^2+b^2}$ if $a,b$ are not both zero. We might then guess that all elements must be of the form $a+br$. [cont]

Comment: [cont] We still haven't proven that such a field exists, but now we have an idea of how to construct one. We take all pairs $(a,b)$ for reals $a,b$ (with the hope that it can represent $a+br$ in the constructed field) and **define** addition by $(a,b)+(c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$ and multiplication by $(a,b) \times (c,d) = (ac-bd,ad+bc)$ (because that is how it must be according to our hope). Then for the same reason as earlier remarked, $(a,b)$ has a multiplicative inverse when $a,b$ are not both zero. Since this structure of pairs has $(0,0)$ as the additive identity, it indeed is a field. [cont]

Comment: [cont] The reals embed into this structure of pairs as elements of the form $(a,0)$, in the sense that all operations are preserved by the embedding, meaning that $a+b=c$ iff $(a,0)+(b,0)=(c,0)$ and $ab=c$ iff $(a,0)(b,0)=(c,0)$, for any reals $a,b$. Mathematicians will usually not go further since an embedding is good enough, as it means that $\{ (a,0) : a \in \mathbb{R} \}$ has essentially the same properties the real numbers. But we can cut out that set from our structure, replace with the **real** real numbers and modify the operations appropriately, to get to the original goal as stated.

Comment: By the way I didn't answer because what I say is technically not an answer to your question as stated, but certainly you need to appreciate the algebraic definition of the complex numbers (which was also the original intended use), before you can see why it is so amazing that it has a geometric interpretation. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/802678 for more.

Comment: @user21820 yes, i know. The purpose of the complex numbers was to fill in the gaping void left from the square root of negative numbers.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Well originally they were called imaginary for good reason, because mathemaicians didn't consider fields in the abstract sense and so they saw no meaning for such a larger field, even if they proved that it is a field. (I'm not sure whether they actually did realize they needed to.) And it was a while later that people found that by putting the complex numbers in a cartesian plane you get geometric interpretations. I didn't read all the answers but the most important one is that adding a complex number is a translation and multiplying by a complex number is a spiral transform.

Comment: And good job on asking a good question! (Votes and getting on the hot question list aside, of course, though that's how I got here.) =)

Comment: @user21820 I never thought of them as imaginary per se. When I first learnt of i, I actually convinced myself it was perpendicular because "negation is mirroring, so half negation must be half mirroring which is... Perpindicular.". I just thought it was nonsense I was randomly thinking up. You can imagine my surprise when I hear of complex numbers a few years later. Anyway, I mostly posted the question to see if there was a more "rigorous reasoning". As for it being a good question, thank you. I appear to have good luck lately with that.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: I posted on Math SE before about precisely that, but cannot find it now. Basically, we can 'explain' the rationale for addition and multiplication of real numbers in terms of translation and scaling, and it intuitively explains division as undoing multiplication. These transformations apply to the real line. Then a natural question is whether we can have half a $-1$-scaling, and the most obvious is to extend to transformations of a plane, where a $90^\circ$ rotation is indeed a desired half. Rotations in a plane commute, and so we still have commutativity of multiplication.

Comment: @alastair kind of touched on this, but the inner product defined on the complex plane immediately implies that the complex numbers lie on a perpendicular axis. That is, if we're going to visualise the complex numbers as living on the plane, then the inner product behaves exactly like that of R^2 only when thr axes are perpendicular. I.e. the projection of a complex number onto a real one is zero.

Answer (score 71):

There is a really important aspect of complex numbers that depends on the complex plane having exactly this shape: complex multiplication.

Complex numbers can not only be characterized in cartesian coordinates by a real part and an imaginary part, but also in polar coordinates by a length and an angle.

You know that for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ there exist $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $z = x+i\cdot y$, right? $x$ is the real part and $y$ is the imaginary part? Well, there also exist $r, \varphi \in \mathbb{R}$, $r \geq 0$ such that $z = r\cdot(\cos\varphi + i\sin\varphi)$. Here, $r$ is called the *length* or *absolute value* of $z$ and $\varphi$ is called the *angle* or *argument*, measured counterclockwise from the positive real axis.

We can use cartesian coordinates to add complex numbers: $$(x_1+i\cdot y_1) + (x_2+i\cdot y_2) = (x_1+x_2) + i\cdot(y_1+y_2)$$

We can use cartesian coordinates to multiply complex numbers:

$$(x_1+i\cdot y_1)\cdot (x_2+i\cdot y_2) = (x_1x_2-y_1y_2) + i\cdot(x_1y_2+y_1x_2)$$

However, we can also use polar coordinates to multiply complex numbers:

$$(r_1(\cos\varphi_1 + i\sin\varphi_1))\cdot(r_2(\cos\varphi_2 + i\sin\varphi_2)) = (r_1\cdot r_2)(\cos(\varphi_1+\varphi_2) + i\sin(\varphi_1+\varphi_2))$$

So to multiply two complex numbers in polar coordinates, you *multiply* their lengths and *add* their angles. I personally think this is incredibly helpful for visualization, and this also shows why the imaginary axis needs to be at a right angle to the real axis: since the angle of $-1$ is $180^\circ$, the angle of $i$ needs to be $90^\circ$ or $270^\circ$.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this also leads to [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) and simplifies the way that complex exponentiation works.

Answer (score 35):

The complex plane is a model (or more formally, an isomorphism) with very nice properties, such as $\arg(zw)=\arg(z)+\arg(w)$ or, in more advanced complex analysis, winding numbers.

Could there be a "better" representation? Maybe. And, in any case, you should be clear about what means "better" for you, that is, what you want to do with this representation.

What is sure is that, since Gauss began to use the complex plane, deep, useful and beautiful applications have been found.

Comment: This answer is so insanely good. Seriously. To anyone reading this: take a moment and let it all sink in.

Comment: What is arg? It looks familiar but I cannot seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Typically, it is used to denote the angle from the positive real axis of your complex number. For example, $\arg(1+i)=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: @TheCount no i am not familiar with that definition. I must be remembering but an unrelated location (probably a function in programming meaning "argument" or something). That makes sense now though.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, it seems that without having already decided on the plane, the arg function looks rather arbitrary. Moreover, winding numbers are purely topological, so they don't tell us anything about the geometry of the plane. (Of course, if we accept that $e^x$ is a nice function, then things like the argument pop out, but that's not mentioned in this answer)

Comment: and the last sentence is rather euphuistic

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: There is the formula $\mathrm{Im}(\log z) = \arg z$.

Comment: @Hurkyl i dont know Im either. My knowledge of complex numbers is just of their shape, form, and basic properties, some of which I understood before even hearing the term "complex number".

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: (Im here means "imaginary part")

Comment: @Hurkyl oh. Log of complex numbers is defined?

Comment: This is really not that useful...

Comment: At the risk or repeating or oversimplifying, I believe that you’re saying that the complex plane is structured the way it is because we choose to plot a complex number $z$ as a point that is geometrically $|z|$ from the origin, with an angle of  $\mathrm{Im}(\log z)$ from the positive real number line (the $\mathrm X$ axis), partly because that turns multiplication of complex numbers into multiplication of real numbers plus addition of angles. (We arbitrarily choose to measure the angle in a counter-clockwise direction because that puts $+i$ above the real axis and $-i\,$ below it.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  We choose to represent the set of real numbers by a straight line because we like the geometric analogy by which real numbers $a$ and $b$ are represented by points that are $|a-b|$ apart — a curved line wouldn’t support that.  (And note that complex numbers $a$ and $b$ are similarly represented by points that are $|a-b|$ apart in the complex plane.)

Comment: Isomorphism of what (category) exactly?

Comment: @Scott-СлаваУкраїні that is very useful. Can I read something like that somewhere?

Answer (score 29):

We *choose* pictorial representations so that algebraic properties (such as associativity and commutativity of addition and multiplication) have coherent geometric interpretations.

For example, the traditional number line associates to each real number $a$ a *displacement from $0$* in such a way that for all real $a$ and $b$,

- Addition corresponds to concatenation of displacements, subtraction $b - a$ is the displacement taking $a$ to $b$, and $|b - a|$ is the distance from $a$ to $b$;
- Multiplication by a positive real $c$ corresponds to *scaling* by $c$ (fixing $0$) and multiplication by $-1$ is the (distance-preserving) reflection across $0$;
- Moving rightward corresponds to the order relation.

There are, however, other geometric ways to represent the field of real numbers. To name one, identify the real number $a$ with the line of slope $\tanh a$ through the origin in the Cartesian plane, and let the reals act by [boost transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Physical_formulation_of_Lorentz_boosts). This is how velocities add in special relativity.

---

The Euclidean plane [*] can be *coordinatized* by fixing an origin $O$, two mutually-perpendicular oriented lines $X$ and $Y$ through $O$, and a unit of length. (Conventionally, we take $X$ horizontal and oriented to the right; $Y$ vertical and oriented upward.) If $P$ is an arbitrary point, there is a unique line $\ell_{Y}$ through $P$ and parallel to $Y$ by the parallel postulate; the unique point of intersection of $\ell_{Y}$ with $X$ defines the *$x$-coordinate of $P$*. The $y$ coordinate of $P$ is defined similarly.

The point $P$ is thereby identified with an *algebraic address*: the ordered pair $(x, y)$ of real numbers. Doing so furnishes a bijective correspondence between the Cartesian plane (the Euclidean plane with the extra structure of the origin, two oriented lines, and a fixed unit of length) and the set $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ of ordered pairs of real numbers.

Because each axis is effectively a number line, the algebraic operations of vector addition acquire geometric meaning, via the parallelogram law for vector addition and the operation of radial scaling centered at the origin for scalar multiplication.

Now, what about complex numbers? Identifying $\mathbf{C} \simeq \mathbf{R}^{2}$ is natural enough: $x + iy \leftrightarrow (x, y)$. Because $i^{2} = -1$, we wish to represent $i$ as a geometric operation that, performed twice in succession, has the effect of multiplying by $-1$, i.e., of rotating the plane by a half-turn about the origin. A quarter turn about the origin accomplishes this. By an *additional convention*, we (usually) take the counterclockwise rotation, so that the positive $x$-axis rotates to the positive $y$-axis. (We could just as consistently have taken the clockwise rotation; the algebraic operation of complex conjugation is a field automorphism.)

Admittedly this is a compressed account; the essential ideas, however, may be easier to see if not every detail is filled in. The bottom line is, the correspondence between algebra and geometry is conventional, though (as other answers note) mathematically rich beyond any reasonable *a priori* expectation.

---

[*] In the original post, I wrote, "Descartes noticed that the Euclidean plane...." As Daniel R. Collins noted in the comments, this assertion is less true than "common knowledge" has it. I'm not a mathematical historian, and can't lay out the complete provenance of Cartesian axes, but axes as described in this answer were not explicitly introduced by Descartes. (The comments contain a few more details.)

Comment: My understanding is that Descrates made use of a one-dimensional line, but not two perpendicular axes; that is properly credited to a later translator of his work, Frans van Schooten, et. al. Suggest either supplying a citation for that use by Descartes or removing his name from that paragraph.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: I haven't read Descartes in French, but the assertion that Descartes didn't coordinatize the plane is new to me. In [_A History of mathematics_](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31061), for example, Florian Cajori (p. 215, ten lines from the bottom) writes, "By him [Descartes], a point on a plane was determined in position by its distance from two fixed right lines or axes." If this well-trodden claim is incorrect, I'd certainly like to know. Do you have sources to the contrary?

Comment: First place I found it was on Wikipedia, with a citation of Burton, David M. (2011), *The History of Mathematics/An Introduction (7th ed.)*, p. 374 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system). Second place is in printed lecture notes by George Smith, Tufts U., Philosophy 167: Science Before Newton’s Principia, Class 8, on Descartes' *Geometry*: "Though not a reduction of geometry to algebra (just the opposite) and no Cartesian coordinates in it"

Comment: Third place Bell E. T. (1945). *Development of Mathematics. 2nd. ed.*:  "In details, Descartes' presentation differs from that now current. Thus, he used only an x-axis and did not refer to a y-axis.", found here: http://4dlab.info/article_short_history_of_the_cartesian_coordinates.htm

Comment: A wealth of good stuff in this answer! Brilliant.

Comment: Emphasis on *mutually perpendicular* as that is why some non-90-degree-angle would not work, as large i would add to the reals direction - not making sense unless numbers added had non-i part.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: Interesting, thanks. The only source to which I have immediate access is the 1886 A. Hermann edition of [_La Géométrie_](http://ebooks.library.cornell.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=math;cc=math;view=toc;subview=short;idno=00570001). At a quick skim I don't see explicit introduction of "axes", but (for example) on page 33 (Fig. 12, ff.), Descartes (modulo my non-fluent French) describes a hyperbola using displacements $x$ and $y$ along mutually perpendicular lines. By chance, the [Clavius Group](http://home.cogeco.ca/~clavius/) is meeting this week; I'll ask around....

Comment: @NoBugs: If the coordinate axes were non-orthogonal lines, multiplication by $i$ could still be represented by a linear transformation $T$ whose square is a half-turn. Of course, $T$ wouldn't be a Euclidean rotation, but something like a rotation conjugated by a shear. I'm not saying this convention would be a _good_ idea, but it wouldn't be mathematically untenable. :)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the reference. Can you specify what book/heading this comes under? I'm looking at a facsimile of the first edition where the page numbers are vastly different.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: The pagination should be for the linked online edition from the Cornell Historical Mathematical Monographs collection. :)

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: Thank you for the correction. :) I've removed the phrase "Descartes noticed that..." and added an explanatory footnote.

Answer (score 15):

[Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Riemann)

[image: Riemann]

made it into a [sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere):

[image: sphere]

Comment: You. Just. Blew. My. Mind. Thank you for the great bit of information!

Comment: Don't worry. They never taught us what the point of this is. They merely stated its existence and then went on with other stuff.

Comment: I am not worried.

Comment: I was wondering when someone would mention this.  Also, I believe its more important in topology than complex analysis.  At least I can't think of any way it'd be useful in complex analysis.

Comment: @Bye_World: Well, among other things, objects that are normally lines become circles through the point at infinity. Which simplifies a lot of theorems so instead of saying "lines do this and circles do that..." you can just say "circles do that..." and it covers both cases.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, should you have time, look up "stereographic projection".

Comment: @J.M. i shall. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the location 0 is at be negative infinity? Also, integers are a lot more condensed at the top than bottom. Is this not a problem? Also, why is -infinity = infinity?

Comment: @Goldname, 1. no; 2. usually the Riemann sphere model is not used in that situation; 3. see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2280092).

Answer (score 8):

This is a long-winded version of some of the answers already posted. Hopefully it helps someone. Be sure to take a look at the comments below for slightly more sophisticated approach.

---

Forget everything you know about the complex number system $\mathbb{C}$ for a moment. Let's turn the question on it's head: suppose we have a two dimensional number system $\mathbb{K} = \{a+b\kappa:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\},$ and suppose our new number $\kappa\not\in\mathbb{R}$ *is* "perpendicular to the real axis," in a sense that we shall soon define precisely. Suppose also that multiplying these numbers behaves nicely, in a precise way. In this answer, we shall show that $\kappa^{2}=-1$ then must be the case. The point is that the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ are not just introduced for no reason (or for some boring reason like quadratic equations): it is useful because it is the *only* number system which behaves nicely enough for our usual purposes. The **answer to the question** is then "the complex plane is shaped like it is *because we want complex numbers to be elegant*".

First, by "a number system", I just mean a set of objects which we can add to each other, subtract from each other, multiply by each other and divide by each other (except by zero!), just like with real numbers.

Next, what do I mean by "perpendicular to the real axis"? We want to be able to draw $\mathbb{K}$ as a plane, with the real axis horizontal and the $\kappa$ axis vertical. Imagine you've drawn the plane (or better yet, actually draw the plane) and pick a point $a+b\kappa\in\mathbb{K}$. This point lies somewhere in the plane. Taking inspiration from our knowledge of the Cartesian plane $\mathbb{R}^{2},$ we define notions of length and angle (or *modulus* and *argument*) corresponding to $a+b\kappa$ as follows:

- Since the point $a+b\kappa$ naturally corresponds to the point $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$, and the length we typically associate with $(a,b)$ is the Euclidean distance to the origin, we define the modulus of $a+b\kappa$ by $$\lvert a+b\kappa \rvert = \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}.$$
- Since the point $a+b\kappa$ naturally corresponds to the point $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$, and the angle we typically associate with $(a,b)$ is the angle to the real axis measured counterclockwise, we define the argument of $a+b\kappa$ by $$\arg{(a+b\kappa)} =\begin{cases}\tan^{-1}{(b/a)} & \text{if }a\neq0\text{ and }b>0,\\-\tan^{-1}{(b/a)} & \text{if }a\neq0\text{ and }b<0,\\\pi/2 & \text{if }a=0\text{ and }b>0,\\-\pi/2 & \text{if }a=0\text{ and }b<0\\0&\text{if }a>0\text{ and }b=0\\\pi&\text{if }a<0\text{ and }b=0.\end{cases}$$ Note that if $a=b=0$, then we leave the argument undefined.

At this point you should probably draw a sketch and make sure this agrees with what we know about coordinate geometry. This definition guarantees in advance that $\arg{\kappa}=\pi/2$, which is the whole point. Also, $\lvert\kappa\rvert=1$ by definition.

Finally, what do I mean by "multiplication of these numbers behaves nicely"? I mean this: multiplication of two numbers in $\mathbb{K}$ should result in a number whose length is the product of their lengths and whose argument is the sum of their arguments.

I understand that this last assertion might seem a bit random, so I'll try to convince you that this is a *reasonable* thing to impose. Note that multiplying any number $a+b\kappa\in\mathbb{K}$ by a positive real number $r>0$ *a priori* does not affect the argument: $$\arg{(r(a+b\kappa))}=\tan^{-1}{\frac{rb}{ra}} = \tan^{-1}{(b/a)} = \arg{(a+b\kappa)}.$$ This means that multiplying $a+b\kappa$ by a positive real number $r$ gives a number whose argument is $\arg{(a+b\kappa)}+0$, and we note here that $0=\arg{r}$. Similarly, multiplying by negative real numbers results in addition of $\pi$ to the argument, which is handy because negative real numbers have argument $\pi$. When it comes to multiplying two arbitrary non-zero numbers in $\mathbb{K}$ together, we would like there to be a rule that fits the current pattern. I've already hinted at the most obvious one: 
$$\text{if }z,w\in\mathbb{K}\setminus\{0\},\text{ then }\arg{(zw)}=\arg{z}+\arg{w}.$$ By very similar reasoning, it makes sense to impose the rule $\lvert zw\rvert =\lvert z\rvert \lvert w\rvert$.

*Side note:* hopefully you agree that these *are* nice properties for our number system to have. The whole point of this discussion is that it would be aesthetically pleasing (and, as it turns out, useful!) to have a number system that follows these rules.

Now, if $\mathbb{K}$ truly behaves as we want it to and follows all the rules we've laid out above, then we have no choice: since $\lvert\kappa\rvert=1$ it follows that $\lvert\kappa^{2}\rvert=1$ and $\arg{\kappa^{2}}=\pi/2+\pi/2=\pi$, and the only number with length $1$ and argument $\pi$ is $-1$. Hence $\kappa^{2}=-1$, and $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: There is perhaps another, slicker, way of looking at this. If we impose only that arguments add together, and we say $\kappa^{2}=e+f\kappa$ for some $e,f\in\Bbb{R}$, then, if $a\neq0\neq c$, calculating the argument of $(a+b\kappa)(c+d\kappa)$ leads us to conclude, by the arctan summation formula, that $$\frac{ad+bc}{ac-bd}=\frac{ad+bc+bdf}{ac+bde}.$$ Now setting $e=-1,f=0$ gives the simplest solution. Unfortunately, I couldn't see a way to show that this is the *only* solution (and I'm not convinced it is), so I abandoned this approach.

Comment: If that equation is true for all $(a,b,c,d)$ (or even for some nonempty open subset of $\Bbb R^4$), then it is certainly the case that $e=-1,f=0$. If you cross multiply you get $(b^2cd+abd^2)(e+1)+(b^2d^2-abcd)f=0$, and the surfaces $b^2cd+abd^2=0$ and $b^2d^2-abcd=0$ are nowhere dense (and neither is a subset of the other), so you can pick points on each surface and not the other to show $e+1=0$ and $f=0$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Nice! So that means that if we want to define a "natural" multiplication on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (using the standard basis and "multiplying out the brackets") for which $\arg$ has this kind of completely additive property, then we have no choice: we must choose $(0,1)^{2}=(-1,0)$, giving $\mathbb{C}$. In some sense this provides motivation for the standard construction of $\mathbb{C}$; or at least, it's a somewhat persuasive *algebraic* reason for $\mathbb{C}$ to be worthy of our attention from the get-go.

Answer (score 5):

Complex numbers can be constructed as couple of real numbers :
$
a+ib=(a,b)
$
with suitable definitions of the operations of sum and product ( see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Formal_development)).
With such definitions a complex number corresponds, in a natural way, to an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we have : $1=(1,0)$ and $i=(0,1)$ and , using the usual representation of an orthogonal system for the coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$, these two vectors, are represented as points, at distance $=1$ from the origin, on two straight lines that forms a $90°$ angle. So  this same representation is also adopted for the complex numbers.

Answer (score 4):

**1.** $90$ degrees is chosen because it geometrically matches what was already working. -1 is 180 degrees around from $1$. When you multiply by $-1$ you rotate $180$.
$$1\cdot(-1)=-1$$
and 
$$(-1) \cdot( -1)=1$$
It works the same way for $i$ except $90$ degrees.
$$1\cdot i=i$$
and
$$i\cdot i=-1$$ 
and
$$90+90=180$$

**2.** Has to do with radians. Radians are more mathematical versions of degrees.
$$360\; \mathrm{degrees}=2\pi\;\mathrm{radians}$$  and

$$re^{\theta i}=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$$ 
In this way of showing imaginary numbers $i=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}$, so this means that $i$ is literally $90$ degrees from $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 4):

Because of complex conjugation, the complex numbers have a natural measure of distance; the "size" (i.e. distance from zero) of a complex number is

$$ \| z \| = \sqrt{z \bar{z}} $$

The right hand side is well-defined in terms of more basic concepts, because $z \bar{z}$ is a nonnegative real number.

More generally, the distance between any two complex numbers is

$$ \text{Distance}(z, w) = \|z - w\| $$

which is enough to reproduce plane geometry. e.g. we can see that $1$ and $i$ are at right angles, because they describe two of the sides of a right triangle with $0$ as the remaining vertex:

$$ \|1\|^2 + \|i\|^2 = \|1-i\|^2 $$

---

Furthermore, the two main ways of expressing complex numbers can be motivated for *purely algebraic* reasons. It is convenient to combine conjugation with addition to split a number into two parts

$$ 2z = (z + \bar{z}) + (z - \bar{z}) $$

The first and second terms ultimately lead to the usual real and imaginary parts of $z$.

Combining with multiplication instead suggests, for $z \neq 0$,

$$ z^2 = (z \bar{z}) \cdot \frac{z}{\bar{z}} $$

The first term leads to the norm as described earlier. The second term leads to reducing $z$ to a "unit vector" $\frac{z}{\|z\|}$ on the circle, and thus basically corresponds to the complex argument (i.e. angular position relative to the origin).

Answer (score 3):

Why are complex numbers graphed like points in $\mathbb{R^2}$? Because we choose too, and as a result of our choices (through trigonometry and algebra) the complex numbers became a very useful and beautiful group of numbers.

We defined the complex numbers.  Both algebraically and geometrically. And choose to define the pure complex unit by:

$$i^2=-1$$

Through the Taylor series and the definition of $i$ we got this astonishing formula.

$$re^{i\theta}=r\cos (\theta)+ir\sin (\theta)$$

In a coordinate system with two perpendicular axis $\mathbb{R^2}$, $r\cos(\theta)$ and $r\sin(\theta)$ are given meaning as we recognize these expressions as components of a triangle with hypotenuse $r$ and angle $\theta$ from the origin. The cosine expression being the horizontal component and the sine being the vertical one. But only in such coordinate system will our trigonometry and geometric knowledge make simple sense. So we decided to use this coordinate system $\mathbb{R^2}$ and as a result of the convenience of $r\cos (\theta)$ and $r\sin (\theta)$, we choose to graph the real component of our complex number in the horizontal axis and the imaginary components in the vertical axis.

And more surprises came when we looked at the geometry of multiplying complex numbers. We graph complex numbers as a whole, thus multiplying by $1$ will get you back to the same complex number, so it's the equivalent of a $360$ degree turn. But multiplying by $-1$ will only get you back to the same complex number if you do it twice, so it's the equivalent of half a $360$ turn, I.e a $180$ degree turn. Multiplying by $i$ four times gets you back to the same number so it's the equivalent of a $90$ degree turn....and furthermore every complex number is given a rotational sense when multiplication is performed.

So as a result of our choices, our choices of how we defined the complex numbers and how we graphed them, we open a door to a brand new set of mathematical tools.

Comment: You say "we choose to define the pure complex unit by: $i^2=−1$. And choose to keep all the same properties (associative, communitive, distributive) over addition and multiplication. And choose to have multiplicative inverses for all complex numbers except $0$, $0$ remained the additive identity, and $1$ remained the multiplicative identity.". This is wrong. You cannot any how choose what you want. You've to first prove that such an object exists. This kind of invalid reasoning is the core of almost all known paradoxes. If what I say isn't clear to you, I suggest you learn logic. All the best.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes a relationship between something algebraic and something geometric is almost magical. A simple example would be the linear functions y = mx + b and graphing these functions to obtain lines in a cartesian plane. Just about any interesting algebraic observation you might make about y=mx + b has a clear geometric counterpart about lines.

The realization of the complex plane as, well, a complex plane is such a relationship. Sure you **could** put the imaginary axis at a non-90 degree angle, but then the relationships between the geometry of your plane and the algebra of complex numbers would all become much less transparent.

Take the group of numbers cos(a) + i sin(a). These form an algebraic group, and with the usual realization they are a circle, and multiplying by one of them is a rotation of the complex plane. However, if you change the angle of the imaginary axis, then your circle is replaced by an ellipse at some skew angle from the real numbers, and multiplying by these numbers does odd deformations of the complex plane instead of simply rotating it.

You can think of the sun as rotating around the earth if you want to, but then physics looks very confusing. When you find how much simpler physics looks when you see the earth as rotating around the sun, you conclude that must be the way things really work.

Comment: Eh but that's only from the viewpoint of the sun. From the viewpoint of the galactic centre the sun and earth are going around it, and their orbits weave in and out of each other, not at all looking like the earth going round the sun. =)

Answer (score 1):

for the beginning we will work on $\mathbb{T}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} ; |z|=1\}$ only because we need to explain the geometric meaning of argument only.

so we begin with what we know all (real numbers) and solving the equation of type $ax^2+bx+c=0$, we know all using canonical form that this equation can be transformed to $y^2=t$ where $t$ is a real number, so we need to explain what is the effect of the square function to a number.

so we draw the real line and we see how this function transform a real number of $\mathbb{T}$ ($1$ and $-1$) first for $1$ we see that the angle which form the vector $1$ (think about the vector whose extremities are $0$ and $1$) is $0$, the application $x\to x^2$ transform $1$ to 1 so the angle stay $0$, but for $-1$  we see that the angle which form the vector $-1$ is $\pi$ and $(-1)^2=1$ so the angle is $2\pi\equiv 0$, so as conclusion we can say that the function square "redoubles the angle" of the vector induced by a number.

as a direct consequence we can say that the equation $x^2=-1$ can't have a real solution because the angle of $x^2$ will be $\pi$ so by the above result the angle of $x$ will be $\pi/2$ which is not a real number, so call this number $i$ and we can define the complex plane as the linear combination of this two "independent" vectors.