# $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not differentiable at $x = 1$. Please give me an easier proof if exists.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, alternative-proof

> Prove that $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not differentiable at $x = 1$.

My proof is here:

> Let $0 < h \leq 2$.
> $\frac{\sqrt{1-(1-h)^2}-\sqrt{1-1^2}}{-h} = \frac{\sqrt{2h-h^2}}{-h} = \frac{2h-h^2}{-h\sqrt{2h-h^2}} = \frac{h-2}{\sqrt{2h-h^2}}$.
> So, $\lim_{h\to 0+} \frac{\sqrt{1-(1-h)^2}-\sqrt{1-1^2}}{-h} = -\infty$.
> So, $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not differentiable at $x = 1$.

I want an easier proof.
Is there any general theorem or general proposition to prove the above fact?

By the way, the following proposition is not true. $f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$ and $g(x) = x^3$ is differentiable at $x = 0$ but $f(g(x)) = x$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

> If $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x = a$ and $g(x)$ is differentiable at $x = b$ and $g(b) = a$, then $f(g(x))$ is not differentiable at $x = b$.

So, we cannot prove as follows:

> $\sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$. And $1-x^2$ is differentiable at $x = 1$. So, $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not differentiable at $x = 1$.

Comment: What is uneasy in this proof ?

Comment: For functions that are not defined in a neighbourhood of the point in question you need to specify what you mean by being differentiable. I guess you mean that the right-limit at $x=0$ exists and it is finite.

Comment: @Martingalo: the function is defined in $[-1,1]$, what do you mean ?

Comment: Well, I mean, there is no "left" and "right" of $-1$ and $1$ so an eventual definition of "differentiability" at those points must be redefined as a left- or right-limit, not limit.

Comment: @Martingalo: I disagree. The plain limit is defined. Review the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of $x\mapsto\sqrt{1-x^2}$ exists only for $-1<x<1$:

$$f'(x)=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Since the function is continuous on $[-1,1]$, we can compute the limits of the derivative. Then
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to1^+}f'(x)&=i\infty\\
\lim_{x\to 1^-}f'(x)&=-\infty
\end{align}

so the function is not differentiable at $x=1$ as we have a two-sided limit (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280052/what-is-imaginary-infinity-i-lim-limits-x-to-infty-x-i-infty) also).

Comment: Ares, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way . . .

On the domain $[-1,1]$, let $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and let $g=f^2$.

If $f$ was differentiable at $x=1$ then by the power rule, the equation
$$
g'=2ff'
$$
would hold at $x=1$, but at $x=1$ the $\text{LHS}$ evaluates to $-2$ (since $g'(x)=-2x$) while the $\text{RHS}$ evaluates to $0$ (since $f(1)=0$).

Comment: quasi, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x) = 1 - x^2$. Then
\begin{align}
g(f(x)) 
&= 1 - \left(\sqrt{1-x^2} \right)^2\\
&= 1 - \left(1-x^2 \right)\\
&= x^2\\
\end{align}
so
$$
(g \circ f)'(x) = 2x \tag{1}
$$ for every $x$.

$f$ is evidently differentiable for $-1 < x < 1$.

**Suppose that $f$ were differentiable at $x = 1$ as well.**

Then (by a version of the chain rule extended to deal with one-sided limits), we'd have
$$
(g\circ f)'(1) = g'(f(1)) \cdot f'(1)
$$
Using equation $1$, this becomes
$$
2 = g'(0) \cdot f'(1)
$$
Now $g'(x) = -2x$, so $g'(0) = 0$, so we would have (assuming $f$ is differentiable!) that
$$
2 = 0 \cdot f'(1)
$$
which is impossible. Hence our assumption that $f$ is differentiable (at $1$) must be incorrect.

Is this "simpler"? Probably not. After all, you have to review your proof of the chain rule to confirm that it works when some/all limits are one-sided. That's straightforward, but involves some writing.

Comment: John Hughes, Thank you very much for your elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-0}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}.$$

You can conclude.

Comment: Yves Daoust, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how much you "want to prove".

The function $f(x)= \sqrt{1-x^2}$ has domain $x\in [-1,1]$. The derivative of $f$, if well-defined, can only be defined on $(-1,1)$. If possible, you can extend the definition to $x=\pm 1$ by taking the left- and right-limits.

The derivative of $f$ is
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2} - \sqrt{1-x^2}}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2} - \sqrt{1-x^2}}{h}\frac{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2} + \sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2} + \sqrt{1-x^2}}= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1-(x+h)^2 -1+x^2}{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2} + \sqrt{1-x^2}}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-2x-h}{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2} + \sqrt{1-x^2}} = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

As you can see the function $f$ is not defined on $x=-1$ or $x=1$, hence $f$ is not differentiable at those points. There is not much proof other than differentiating $f$ and looking at its definition domain.

Comment: Martingalo, Thank you very much for your answer.